# ModRewrite urls on page to remove extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Is it possible to change all links on page to remove extension.

```
Example:
www.domain.com/index.php
changes to
www.domain.com/index
```

I want the actual links on the page to change so that when the user hovers over a link it doesn't have the php extension, rather than just doing a redirect everytime. I'm not sure if it is possible but I would prefer to do it this way rather than having to change all my code to remove the php extensions.

Also can I rewrite every link such as:

```
www.domain.com/index?id=12&sid=2
to
www.domain.com/index/id/12/sid/2
```

or do I have to do it manually for each page I want to do it for.

Thanks for you help in advance!

Comment: So, just to clarify, you want every page parsed before it gets sent to the client and all URL references to '.php' removed?

Comment: yes, so if you had this:

<li><a href="index.php" title="">Home Page</a></li>
   </li>
 <li><a href="about.php" title="About">About Us</a></li>

then the href="index.php" will be rewritten to href="index"

Answer (score 1):

Sure. I suppose I would do this by using output buffering. So I'd put ob_start(); at the top of the page (before any output), then at the bottom $contents = ob_get_contents();

Then you'd need a set of regular expressions to make the changes. The details here depend on how you've constructed your site, like if there are full URLs or relative links; if you've been consistent about using double or single quotes for attributes, etc. But something like:

```
$urls = preg_match_all( '|href="http://www.domain.com/[^"]+\.php?[^"]+"|', $contents, $m );
foreach( $m as $u ) {
  $n = preg_replace( "/\?|=|&/", '/', $u );
  $contents = str_replace( $u, $n, $contents );
}
$contents = preg_replace( '|(href="http://www.domain.com/[^"]+)\.php|', $1, $contents );
echo $contents;
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the .php is simple, adding the rewrite can be tricky.

The way wordpress (and a lot of other scripts) do it is via redirecting everything for a PHP script:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

You could have a read through the code and backwards engineer a similar solution to that.

Alternatively if the URLs will always be the same (e.g. always be id=12&sid=2 type of thing) you could add a rewrite rule - something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/index\.php\/?id\=([0-9]+)&sid=([0-9]+)$ /index/id/{$1}/sid/{$2}
```

That's just pseudo - syntax might need a check.

Also, are you using a pre-packaged software package? If so, it may already have the option. Please let us know.

Comment: It is just a standard apache server.


I was really looking to see if it was possible to rewrite every link on the page without having to go through all my code where I link to a page and remove the .php extension from it.

Comment: Well the code above (or a derivative of it) should work for that. As long as the URLs have some sort of standard you can just write a regex to catch the variables (like the id and sid) and rewrite them into a new URL.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add an .htaccess file in your root directory containing this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /router.php
```

what this will do : redirect every request to a file that doesn't exist to your router.php file. What I do is this, in my router.php file, I check what is the url (www.domain.com/index) and then include the good file. Example :

```
$requestURI = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
if (isset ($requestURI[1]) && (resquestURI[1] === "index"){
    require "index.php";
}
else {
    //file not found
}
```

For the "?". I don't think you can remove it, it is used to separate your GET parameters from the url.

Comment: I used that to route everything in my app, it is very usefull. In my app I read the url like this : www.domain.com/controller/view

Comment: So now when you will make links to your website, don't put the .php extension, directly use "www.domain.com/index"